# Degree distribution of a graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

Given a graph, what is the ***degree distribution*** of the same?

Is degree distribution the same as a histogram of the degrees? As in, is the degree distribution a plot of the number of nodes that have a particular degree?

Secondly, is there a probability component to degree distribution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The degree distribution $P(k)$ of a network is then defined to be the fraction of nodes in the network with degree $k$. Thus if there are $n$ nodes in total in a network and $n_k$ of them have degree $k$, we have $P(k) = n_k/n$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_distribution

Comment: @hhsaffar So it is essentially just the fraction of nodes having a degree _k_. Similar to a histogram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The degree distribution of a nonempty finite graph $G$ with vertex set $V(G)$ is the measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb N_0$ defined by $\mu(\{n\})=\#\{x\in V(G)\mid\deg_G(x)=n\}/\#V(G)$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N_0$.

*In words, the degree distribution assigns to each nonnegative integer a weight equal to the proportion of vertices whose degree is this integer. Likewise, for every property blabla, the blabla distribution assigns to each set of values of blabla a weight equal to the proportion of vertices whose blabla is in this set.*

If $G$ is a random graph, that is, if $G$ is a random variable defined on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathfrak F,P)$ with values in the space of nonempty finite graphs suitably endowed with a sigma-algebra, then $\mu$ defined as before becomes a random distribution on $\mathbb N_0$, defined by 
$$\mu(\omega)(\{n\})=\#\{x\in V(G(\omega))\mid\deg_{G(\omega)}(x)=n\}/\#V(G(\omega)),
$$
for every $n$ in $\mathbb N_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I sound naive but I am not a mathematician. Could you perhaps put it in simpler words? Thanks again!

Comment: Could you perhaps mention *which* words are not *simple* enough to be understood by you, not a mathematician?

Comment: @PraveshParekh Suppose you want to know what fraction of the nodes in the graph has a degree equal to $n$. $\mu(n)$ gives you the ratio

Comment: @Did Pardon my naivety but I was wondering if you could explain the answer in words. Understanding it in symbols is a little complex. Thanks.

Comment: So, "in simpler words" actually meant "with no maths symbols"? See Edit.